# Mersenne Twister init_by_array() function clarification

Tags: c, function, random, mersenne-twister

I trying to implement cross-platform consistent random number generation with a 32-bit seed.
Most post point me to [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) or writing my own implementation.

In the [source code](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c) there is a function called void init_by_array().

Is the only purpose of this function to extend the seed passed 32-bit?

From the [ReadMe](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/readme-mt.txt)

> init_by_array(init_key, key_length) initializes the state vector 
>   by using an array init_key[] of unsigned 32-bit integers
>   of length key_kength. If key_length is smaller than 624,
>   then each array of 32-bit integers gives distinct initial
>   state vector. This is useful if you want a larger seed space
>   than 32-bit word.

Failing to understand this just assuming based on the last sentence.

The code seems to run fine only using init_genrand() and seems to be producing consistent results.

Comment: This: http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html *may* be related to your concerns.

Comment: @Bob__ Interesting read. Predictability section is of particular interested.

Comment: @DevilBinder predictability of MT is well known, and even described in the original MT paper: it is part of the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mersenne Twister has 19937 bits of state space that it uses to iterate through the sequence of values it produces.  If you initialize it with a 32 bit integer, you are restricting it to just 2<sup>32</sup> out of the 2<sup>19937</sup> possible starting points, and there are a massive number of sample trajectories that you will never see. The `init_by_array()` function allows you to specify more bits for the initial state, giving the potential to achieve any of the sampling trajectories which MT is capable of generating.

Comment: I appreciate this was a while ago, but I notice that if I seed Random() with a 32-bit integer (or smaller) then it still ends up going through the init_by_array function and hence comes to a different value for the internal state than the reference twister without this function. Do you know why that design decision was made? Why wouldn't it be the case to only call init_by_array when you give an input > 32 bits?

Comment: @whatf0xx [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=RDNtEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=%22initial+state+has+too+many+zeros%22+%22mersenne%22&source=bl&ots=794ptcRgU1&sig=ACfU3U1ZVhOOOdHj28WSk2h-xt4rVByffg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2iMuF4dODAxX9RDABHbtfAscQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22initial%20state%20has%20too%20many%20zeros%22%20%22mersenne%22&f=false) points out that MT performs poorly if the initial state has too many zeros. Default initializers are designed to avoid this, even if seeded with only a 32 bit quantity (where by inference all the other state bits would be zeros).